# Proving the existence of the minimum of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that, given a real continuous function $f(x)$ defined in $(a,\infty)$ with $a$ finite and such that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l$,  $\lim_{x \to\infty} f(x) = \infty$, if there is a point $x_0>a$ where $f(x_0)<l$ then the function has (at least) a minimum. I was thinking to use Weierstrass theorem, but the theorem applies to continuous functions defined on compact intervals... Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>l$ if $x>\delta$ cleary that $\delta>x_0$, now as $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=l$ there is a $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ if $a<x<a+\epsilon$, now use Weiertrass theorem on $[a+\epsilon,\delta]$.

Answer (score 0):

Rolles theorem should do this one! Rolle's theorem essentially states that any real-valued differentiable function that attains equal values at two distinct points must have at least one stationary point somewhere between them